# Satisfying all but one of the axioms for a topology

Tags: general-topology

Problem 1.10 Give an example of a set X and a collection of subsets of X s.t $\mathcal T$ which is not a topology on X but satisfies all the conditions for a topology except for arbitrary union over index sets; however union over countable index sets must hold.

let $ X=[0,1]$ then let $\mathcal T $ be all the countable subsets of X with X and $\emptyset $ clearly a countable union of countable sets is countable. and finite intersection of countable sets is countable. but if we take the the union of every singleton in the interval $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ clearly the arbitrary union is an uncountably infinite set.

I don't like this example can anyone find a better one?

Comment: It's a fine example.

Comment: It was the best i could come up with; please suggest a title for a topology question that is not about topology and i will change it to that.

Comment: I like your title, but a more normal title might be: "Satisfying all but one of the axioms for a topology".

Comment: Presuming you mean closure under unions by the "third condition", just consider an example $T$ which is an algebra over $X$ but not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I think the example is great. I suppose you want an example that appears "in nature," but I'm not sure what an obvious one would be, since interesting things in nature are often actual topologies!

Comment: @MCT thats exactly what i mean it just feels intentionally fabricated, or unauthentic... I mean works but it would be nice to see a "natural example" that failed in such a way

Comment: How are we supposed to know what are the first, second, and third condition for a topology, unless we (a) know what book you are using and (b) have a copy of the same book? I thought there were ***four*** conditions for a topology, but I didn't know that they come in any particular order.

Comment: @bof it's very inferrable from reading the example :) [also only one of them fails if they "only" work for countable]; but yes, would be better to be explicit

Comment: @MCT That's not much of an excuse for not stating the question properly.

Comment: (1) $X\subseteq\overline X,$ (2) $\overline\emptyset=\emptyset,$ (3) $\overline{X\cup Y}=\overline X\cup\overline Y,$ (4) $\overline{\overline X}=\overline X.$

Comment: Seems i lied i have never seen those as the definition in any topology book i have ever looked at. the axioms most people use are. 1) X, $\emptyset \in \mathcal T $ 2) closed under finite intersection, 3) closed under arbitrary union.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example that is seen 'in the wild' is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R),$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R,$ which the closure of all the open sets in $\mathbb R$ under countable unions, intersections and complements. It's a bit tricky to show it's not closed under arbitrary unions. You can observe that any singleton is in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$, so if it were closed under arbitrary unions, every subset of $\mathbb R$ would be in $\mathcal B(\mathbb R).$ But this can't be cause the cardinality of $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ is only $2^{\aleph_0},$ which can be shown by a transfinite induction argument. (Alternatively, it is probably easier to show that the Vitali set is not in $\mathcal B (\mathbb R).$ )

Comment: Very clever example thank you!